# Camera rotation with mouse but dont stop

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, mouse, panning

I have a question I made a game where you controll an spacecraft and use the mouse/keyboard to move. I use the mouse to rotate the ship up, down left and right. Works like a charm. Only problem is when I stop moving the mouse the ship also stops. So If I want to rotate the ship a few times I need to run a marathon with my mouse. This is because I use the Input.Axis(Mouse X) and thats zero when you stop moving the mouse.

So what I want is: Rotate the ship lets say left if I move my mouse a bit to the left and only stop when I return the mouse to the centerarea. I have this code ATM

```
    var c = Camera.main.transform;
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    c.Rotate(0, mouseX * sensitivity, 0);
    c.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity, 0, 0);
    c.Rotate(0, 0, -Input.GetAxis("QandE") * 90 * Time.deltaTime);
```

How can I accomplish this

Comment: So use the mouse position as you can calculate the middle and form a "dead patch" around it (as no one is likely to be pixel perfect slap on the middle) and you can even consider doing some form of the further from the middle the faster you turn or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BugFinder's answer is correct. Here it is in code, for rotating around the Y axis. You can build on it to get your other axes working.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Roll : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = .001f;

    Transform c;

    void Start()
    {
        c = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;

        float dx = 0;

        if (mouse.x > 1000)
            dx = mouse.x - 1000;

        if (mouse.x < 920)
            dx = mouse.x - 920;

        c.Rotate(0, dx * sensitivity, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you. only thing now is that if I move to fast or something my spaceships rolls/rotates.

Comment: Glad it worked! Try different sensitivities and also consider clamping the movement. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted, so I can add the reputation points. Thanks!